# Is there a way to import excel file to data grid view without having Excel or Access DataBase Engine installed?

Tags: c#, database, excel, datagridview, ole

I've found there is already a way to import Excel file to DataGridView if you have Excel or Access Database Engine installed in your PC. I have an application which I want it to work without having to install Excel itself or Access Database Engine. Is there a way that I can do that without installing any of these tools?

It is not a database project. I just need to get some data from a certain Excel file to DataGridView.

Comment: Try GemBox, but it's not free. http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/

Comment: 500$ is a lot. i'd need a chepaper software or a free one if there is no other way i can import the file.

Comment: Certainly. Pick a more suitable database for your application than Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPPlus is a fantastic free library (donate-ware) for reading or creating Excel files. I've used it in several projects over the years and is very flexible. It supports the older XLS and newer XLSX formats.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

It's also available as NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus